# legend alignment in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, legend

I'm trying to get labels left-aligned and values right-aligned in the legend. In below code, I've tried with format method, but the values are not properly aligned.

Any hint/suggestions is greatly appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

# make a square figure and axes
pl.figure(1, figsize=(6,6))

labels = 'FrogsWithTail', 'FrogsWithoutTail', 'DogsWithTail', 'DogsWithoutTail'
fracs = [12113,8937,45190, 10]

explode=(0, 0.05, 0, 0)
pl.pie(fracs, explode=explode, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True)
pl.title('Raining Hogs and Dogs', bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5})

legends = ['{:<10}-{:>8,d}'.format(labels[idx], fracs[idx]) for idx in    range(len(labels))]

pl.legend(legends, loc=1)

pl.show()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two problems with your implementation.  First, your pie slice labels are much longer than the number of characters you allocate to them with `.format()` (the longest is 16 characters and you only allowed space for up to 10 characters).  To fix this, change the `legend` line to:

```
legends = ['{:<16}-{:>8,d}'.format(labels[idx], fracs[idx]) for idx in    range(len(labels))]
                ^-- change this character
```

However, this only improves things slightly.  This is because matplotlib is using a variable-width font by default, meaning characters like *m* take up more space than characters like *i*.  This is fixed by using a fixed-width font.  In matplotlib, this is achieved by:

```
pl.legend(legends, loc=1, prop={'family': 'monospace'})
```

The result lines up nicely, but the monospace font has the downside of being slightly ugly to some:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that did the magic. I did have larger width specified for label, but ended up pasting my older version of code.  setting 'monospace' property did the work. thanks, once again @drs.